# get_field() returns wrong data

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF repeater fields and I am trying to write a function which counts the number of rows of the repeater. The function returns 1 even if the number of rows in a repeater are 0 or more than 0. 
Can someone help me to fix this ?

```
$rows = get_field('sub_seminars');
$row_count = count($rows);
echo count($row_count);
```

A `var_dump` also returns `int(1)` even if the number of rows in a repeater are 0 or more than 0.

Comment: check this  echo $row_count;

Comment: Still no luck @anju

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's have a look at your code:

```
$rows = get_field('sub_seminars');
$row_count = count($rows);  //returning some digit
echo count($row_count);  //counting the returned digit
```

You are double counting the returned count and that is why it is returning 1. Try this:

```
$rows = get_field('sub_seminars');
$row_count = count($rows);     //will return a digit
echo $row_count;  //echo the count
```

Comment: Thanks @roundAbout

Comment: Happy to help @Damon